# Difference between "insensitive" and "not sensitive"

Tags: word-usage

Is there any subtle difference implied when using "insensitive" as compared to "not sensitive"?

I am writing: A is insensitive to changes in B.

But someone suggested that it conveys a strong conclusion (and would need more explanation) and instead I should use "not sensitive".

[ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=insensitive%2Cnot+sensitive&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cinsensitive%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Binsensitive%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BInsensitive%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cnot%20sensitive%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bnot%20sensitive%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNot%20sensitive%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1):

**Insensitive** adj:

1. lacking sensitivity; unfeeling
2. lacking physical sensation
3. (foll by: to) not sensitive (to) or affected (by): insensitive to radiation.

Source: Collins Dictionary

NGram shows a wider use of *insensitive* vs *non sensitive* and that probably makes its meaning sound more "aggressive" though they convey the same concept.

I think it is like when you prefer  using *not good* instead of *bad*, the former is a more polite way to convey a similar meaning.

I'd say that *insensitive is* more emphatic than *non sensitive.*